CentOS 9 / AlmaLinux 9 / Rocky Linux 9 and xtables-addons: xt_geoip missing kernel module
I'm trying to get working xt_geoip extension on RHEL 9 compatible OSes. I've installed xtables-addons from rpmfusion repo and the xt_geoip extension was working for a while, but after OS reinstallation when I use command: iptables -A INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc PL -j DROP I got interesting message:
Warning: Extension geoip is not supported, missing kernel module?
iptables v1.8.10 (nf_tables): Couldn't load match `geoip':No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

This a bit strange, because indeed there's no xt_geoip module loaded and even it doesn't exists and can't load it using modprobe xt_geoip. Of course GeoIP database is correctly installed in /usr/share/xt_geoip, was working.
I was using xt_geoip for long time, but I need to upgrade my servers to the most recent RHEL and I very need it, as this is an important part of the system.
Does anyone know what may be a reason of this problem?
